# Script that wipes hard drive, installs Debian, and configures GRUB stuck on "GRUB" message after boot

Tags: bash, debian, boot, grub

I'm writing a script that is intended to run from a Debian-based live image. Its goal is to wipe all data off the primary hard drive, install Debian Buster (via `debootstrap`), and then configure GRUB to allow for automatic booting of the system partition. This is the first step in a larger project.

The script seems to run without issues. However, when I go to boot into the newly created system, I am given a screen that says the word `GRUB` and nothing else - not even a GRUB prompt.

What am I missing? Here is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Please run script as root user." >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Install prerequisites
apt update
apt install debootstrap

# Wipe out drive and set up GPT table
umount /mnt/*
fuser -km /dev/sda*
sgdisk --zap-all /dev/sda
parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt

# hd0,1
parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 0% 512MB
parted /dev/sda set 1 boot on
parted /dev/sda set 1 bios_grub on
yes | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1

# hd0,2
parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 512MB 100%
yes | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2

mkdir -p /mnt/root
mkdir -p /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/root

# Set up Operating System
debootstrap --arch=amd64 buster /mnt/root http://deb.debian.org/debian/

mount --bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/root/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/root/sys

# chroot to install programs
chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash << "EOT"

# Add the community repositories to the sources list
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update -y

# Packages to install
apt install -y grub-pc grub-common
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
update-grub
EOT
```

Comment: Have you tweaked that script to add verbose/debugging messaging at each step to ensure they are **each** and **individually** successful, in order to determine the point of breakdown?  I would add messaging actions in the style ... **test $? -eq 0 || { echo "FAILED at step ##" >&2 ; exit 1 }** ... in order to ensure 100% sanity check along the way.

Comment: Maybe not directly related, but for one you mounted `boot/` wrong. You should mount `/dev/sda2` on `/mnt/root/boot` *after* mounting `/dev/sda1` on `/mnt/root`.

Comment: Also bios_boot is not the same thing as a `/boot` partition. The former is crucial for i386-pc (BIOS) grub on GPT, where an image would be embedded so no formation should be done. Separate `/boot` partition is optional though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some pointed out in the comments to the post above, I had been doing several things wrong.

1. I had been combining MBR with GPT. I decided to go with the older MBR approach to partitioning, which meant that `parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt` became `parted /dev/sda mklabel msdos`.
2. I needed to have mounted my `/boot` partition into the primary filesystem, even if it sat on a different partition. Mounting `/dev/sda2/` to `mnt/root/boot` (as mentioned above) works.
3. I don't need the `parted /dev/sda set 1 bios_grub on` command.
4. `debootstrap` doesn't install a kernel. I can do that from `apt` from within a `chroot` shell (as shown below).

**Here is the final script that actually works:**

```
#!/bin/sh

if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
    echo "Internet connection successful."
else
    echo "Internet is not connected. Setup cannot continue."
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Please run script as root user." >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Install prerequisites
apt update
apt install debootstrap

# Wipe out drive and set up GPT table
umount /mnt/*
fuser -km /dev/sda*
sgdisk --zap-all /dev/sda
parted /dev/sda mklabel msdos

# hd0,1
parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 0% 512MB
parted /dev/sda set 1 boot on
parted /dev/sda set 1 bios_grub on
yes | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1

# hd0,2
parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 512MB 100%
yes | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2

mkdir -p /mnt/root
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/root
mkdir -p /mnt/root/boot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root/boot

# Set up Operating System
debootstrap --arch=amd64 buster /mnt/root http://deb.debian.org/debian/

mount --bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/root/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/root/sys

# chroot to install programs
chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash << "EOT"

# Add the community repositories to the sources list
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update -y
apt upgrade -y

# Install Linux kernel
apt install -y linux-image-amd64 grub-pc grub-common
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo "GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\"" > /etc/default/grub
update-grub

# Set up users
apt install -y sudo
useradd agent
echo "root:Shebang01#!" | chpasswd
echo "agent:Shebang01#!" | chpasswd
usermod -aG sudo agent

# Set up internet
echo graphene-hostname > /etc/hostname
echo "auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d" > /etc/network/interfaces
apt install -y network-manager
[5:48 PM]
# Desktop
apt install -y xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-core xinit fonts-liberation fonts-dejavu fonts-droid-fallback fonts-noto fonts-roboto openbox qterminal xscreensaver pulseaudio
echo "/dev/sda2 /   ext4    defaults    0   0" > /etc/fstab

# edit /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty\@tty1.service so that ExecStart reads:
# ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -p "" -a myuser %I $TERM

# Install laptop + portability utilities
# apt install -y wireless-tools acpi-support cpufrequtils acpi wpasupplicant powertop acpid apmd pcmciautils pm-utils anacron avahi-autoipd bluetooth

# Common apps
apt install -y chromium

apt autoremove -y
EOT
```